# Entire functions with fixed values on the integer lattice

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, weierstrass-factorization

Do there exist two distinct entire functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, neither of which is identically constant **and such that f / g is non-constant***, such that
$$f(m + n\:i) = g(m + n\:i)$$
for all $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$?

Certainly, if two such functions exist, then at least one has an essential singularity at infinity.  Indeed, define $h(z) := f(1/z) - g(1/z)$, which is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$.  Since $h$ is zero on a sequence converging to the origin, it is either holomorphic there (implying $f\equiv g$ by the identity theorem) or has an essential singularity: a pole is not an option since that would imply $|f(w_n)|\rightarrow \infty$ for all $w_n$ converging to zero.  Therefore, either $f$ or $g$ has an essential singularity at the origin.

I have a feeling that either Picard's Great Theorem or Weierstrass factorization, both of which I have only passing knowledge of, could be useful.  Any ideas?

(PS: I did a search before posting and see plenty of answers on the existence of such a function, but none so far on its uniqueness.)

***The bolded condition has been added because, as user Conrad points out, we can simply scale $f$ up by a multiplicative constant.**

Comment: Pick one (nonconstant) $f$ that vanishes on the lattice (use weierstrass factors to construct it) and then $g =2f$ definitely is equal to $f$ on the lattice

Comment: @Conrad Good answer that I probably should have thought of first!  ;)

Comment: @Conrad Okay, let's make this harder.  Suppose we add the additional restriction that f/g cannot be constant ... what then?

Comment: It's the same, pick a nonconstant $h$ vanishing on the lattice and take, say, $f  = z, g = z + h$. The point is that your condition is equivalent to $f - g$ vanishing on the lattice so the question reduces pretty much immediately to the question of whether there are nonconstant entire such functions.

Comment: Also $e^zf, f$ give examples where the functions precisely vanish only on the lattice etc